# Makeindex in TeXnicCenter

Tags: indexing, texniccenter

I need to create an index in my document, so I put the following lines in my preambel

```
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{showidx}
\makeindex
```

So, when compiling with TeXnicCenter, I noticed the following line in the log

```
Can't create output index file E:\...\doc.ind
```

No further information on why - just this line. Of course, in the compiled document, there is no index (duh!) - So, why does this error ocurr and how can I get TeXnicCenter to produce the index file?

If I run makeindex myself over cmd, it runs smoothly and creates the index without a problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In current versions of the common TeX distributions (MiKTeX 2.9, TeX Live 2010) MakeIndex as well as BibTeX have got a security mechanism that prevents them from processing files with absolute paths. Therefore you have to modify the settings in TeXnicCenter (TXC) as shown in the picture. Replace "%bm" with "%tm" wherever you can find it in your build profiles.

---

[image]

Comment: Wow, how do you figure out something like this? That's the last thing I would've checked... Still, a problem remains: When I index something using `\index{word}`, and I `\printindex` it, the entry is `indexfile, 7` instead of `word, 7`

Comment: Such things get about. Perhaps this special issue can be found in the manual of the concerned TeX distribution. I can't remember where I got it from. Regarding your problem you are better with closing this question and opening a new one to receive detailed answers.

Comment: same here ... I'm glad I stumbled over this entry more or less by chance.
All's well after changing %bm to %tm though I don't understand why :-)

Comment: @Nicholas Lack: Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank Thorsten by upvoting his answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so I converted your non-answer to a comment. You can't add comments to other posts as long you don't have 50 reputation.