# Problem with makeindex

Tags: memoir, indexing

I'm trying to create an index of manually-added words in `memoir`.  I've looked up instructions in the documentation, and came up with the following MWE.  It compiles, but why is the index not showing up?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeindex
\indexintoc

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents*

\mainmatter
\chapter{My chapter}
\noindent This is some text.
\index{text}

\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run `makeindex`, and then rerun `pdflatex`?

Comment: @PeterGrill I put the `\makeindex` command in the document, if that's what you mean...?

Comment: No. There is a separate executable you need to invoke. First run `pdflatex` (which produces the .idx file), then `MakeIndex` which generates the .ind file, which is read by the subsequent run of `pdflatex` which produces the index.

Comment: @PeterGrill I checked, and it turns out TeXnicCenter is indeed (automatically) calling `makeindex.exe` (after `pdflatex`)--but still no index is showing up.  Do any command-line arguments need to be written alongside `makeindex.exe`?  (Also, is it necessary to have the line `\makeindex` in the document?)

Comment: Yet again a great chance to mention `latexmk` which will take care of all this by itself. That is, you have to take care of the code, and `latexmk` will take care of the compilation in terms of the different executables that have to be run, the order etc.

Comment: Just for fun, and to rule out the editor, try running Peters solution, i.e. `pdflatex`, `makeindex`, `pdflatex`, in a terminal, that is by not using an editor. Or try using TeXMaker instead (I'm not a big fan of TeXnicCenter)

Comment: Thank you to all the commentators!  It turns out the problem was with TeXnicCenter, which wasn't calling `makeindex` properly.  [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17190/9757) (from the question @PeterGrill linked to in his answer) provided the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To generate an index, you need to:

1. Run `pdflatex` which produces the `.idx` file
2. Run `MakeIndex` which generated the `.ind` file
3. Run `pdflatex` which will then incorporate the `.ind` file and produce the index page.

For issues related specifically to TeXnicCenter, see [Makeindex in TeXnicCenter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/makeindex-in-texniccenter)